# Fonts and Colors extension .ctp of Cake in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

how do i change or add the color to file **.ctp** of *CakePhp* in *Visual Studio 2013* or *2017*

The way I visualize it:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you have https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.PHPToolsforVisualStudio installed?

Comment: Yes i Have Installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ctp` is cake's file extension for view files, which are written in php.  So you really want them to be highlighted as if they were php.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension` in Visual Studio.  Enter the file extension `.ctp` and associate it with php.